# Python код для подсчета гласных в массиве, вводимом вручную

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть код который должен считать только гласные в массиве, но он также считает и согласные, в чем проблема?

```
arr = []
vowels = 0
a=0
kekw = []
def itemType(kekw):
    for i in range(15):
        print(type(kekw[i]))


while True:
    newItem = input('Введите "STOP" для остановки.')
    if newItem == 'STOP':
        break
    else:
      if(newItem.isnumeric()):
        kekw.append(int(newItem))
      else:
        kekw.append(newItem)
count = 0
for i in range(15):
    vowels = 'а' or 'у' or 'о' or 'ы' or 'э' or 'я' or 'ю' or 'ё' or 'и' or 'е'
    if type(kekw[i])!=int:
        for vowels in kekw[i]:
            count +=1
print(count)
```

Comment: это `vowels = 'а' or 'у' or 'о' or...` так не работает.

Comment: А как тогда это правильно сделать?

Comment: А вот это `if(newItem.isnumeric()):` какое отношение к гласным имеет?

Comment: Он задает тип str для элемента массива, верхний задает int,  без них не работало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
kekw = []
vowels = 'ауоыэяюёие'

while True:
    newItem = input('Введите некоторое выражение или Enter для выхода: ')
    if not newItem:
        break
    else:
        kekw.append(newItem)
            
for text in kekw:
    count = 0
    for l in text:
        if l in vowels:
            count += 1
           
    print(f'{text} - гласных букв: {count}')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, попробую опираясь на ваш вариант переделать свой

Comment: @SorryBro это и есть переделанный ваш код. Мой ответ- решает вашу проблему?

Comment: Да, спасибо большое

Comment: @SorryBro пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour